# Camera Calibration Library

Tags: matlab, opencv, camera-calibration, matlab-cvst

I'm looking for good library for camera calibration, I'm aware of [Camera Calibration Toolbox for Matlab](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) and [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html). The problem with the toolbox is that it is in Matlab and not very friendly for modifications. OpenCV on the other hand seems to be less precise (see [Suriansky](http://www.daaam.info/Downloads/Pdfs/proceedings/proceedings_2012/0365_Suriansky&Cmarada.pdf)).

So are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

The paper you cite is rubbish: whoever wrote it did not bother to actually read the code.

The Matlab toolbox uses exactly the same calibration algorithms as the OpenCV code: Zhang's for the initial estimation, followed by a round of bundle adjustment. The reason they are very similar is that the author of the original implementation of the Matlab toolbox worked for a while with the Intel team that produced the calibration code in the very first release of OpenCV.

Any differences among the results they produce are most likely due to different configurations of the control parameters.

I don't understand what you mean by "not very friendly for modification". If you have Matlab, and your application can use it (it's slow), J.Y. Bouguet's code is quite easy to read and modify. On the other hand, I always found the OpenCV codebase somewhat annoyingly low-level (but understandably so, given the stress on performance).

Comment: Isn't the Matlab camera calibration toolbox using Heikkilä's 'A Four-step Camera Calibration Procedure with Implicit Image Correction'?

Comment: Only for the nonlinear distortion model. See the first two entries in the list of references here http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/ref.html , or read the code yourself.

Comment: True. Thanks for the correction and the interesting link.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is the [camera calibration functionality](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/geometric-camera-calibration.html) in the Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB. Specifically, check out the [Camera Calibrator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/single-camera-calibrator-app.html) and the [Stereo Camera Calibrator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-camera-calibrator-app.html) apps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Francesco, both Matlab and OpenCV use the Zhang method. As 2022, OpenCV offers a larger range of distortion parameters thus offering more precision in the pose estimation results. However, all parameters might not be required at once. More details on these parameters are provided in the documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga3207604e4b1a1758aa66acb6ed5aa65d

As an alternative solution to both OpenCV and Matlab, I would definitely recommend [CalibPro](https://calibpro.com), a web platform that allows you to upload your data and get your calibration parameters in a matter of minutes without a single line of code. CalibPro is fully compatible with OpenCV camera parameters. The platform is rapidly developing and will provide more than the pinhole camera model in the near future.

[Disclaimer]: I am the founder of CalibPro. I am happy to take any feedback on our platform or help people with their calibration.